# View in accessible in kotlin classs, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, view

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint = 'your name'
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

This is my main xml file and I'm trying to get the input using EditText View. But in kotlin file this view is not accessible, it suggests to create a new variable

```
    val name  = editText.text.toString()
    Toast.makeText(this, "name is $name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

editText is not recognized

Comment: did you use findViewById ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `edittext` then first you do `findViewById()` like this

```
val edtName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
```

Now you can access your editext like this

```
val name  = edtName.text.toString()
Toast.makeText(this, "name is $name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

if you use **View Binding** then you don't need to use `findViewById()` to bind your view in your activity file

Please read more about [**View Binding**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)